# Remove leading zero with date formatter objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdateformatter

I set date format to `@"HH:mm"`
This works if the hour is double digits. but if the hour is a single digit, I need to set format to `@"H:mm"` so it displays `9:00`, rather than `09:00`. How can I parse NSDate or automatically detect which format I need to use?

Comment: Just use `H:mm` and it will automatically show one or two digits, as needed.

Comment: Unrelated, but I’m curious why you’re asking. If this was for the UI, you’d generally not use `dateFormat` at all, and instead set `timeStyle` to `.short` and honor the user’s preferences for 12/24 hour clocks. But if it wasn’t for the UI, e.g. for exchanging with some web service, then for ISO 8601/RFC 3999 dates, two digit hour format is preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `H:m` and it will parse time strings such as `9:1`, `09:05`, `12:1`, or `12:07`, etc.

If you want to create a time string from an `NSDate` then use `H:mm`. This will give `9:15` or `12:15`, etc.